# How to Increase Transaction per second(TPS) in cassandra by using DataStax java Driver

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

**The setup:**

- 2-node Cassandra 2.0.7.31 cluster
- replicas=1
- DataStax java driver 2.0

**Problem**

I am using Datastax java driver for load balancing. 
 
I and generating 50000+ thread load by Jmeter 
but getting very low TPS. **near about 1700 tps** 
 
I have not changed any performance related parameter In cassandra.yaml
 can any one suggest which parameter should I use to get satisfactory TPS. I herd Most of the Folks are getting 10000+ tps with Cassandra.

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1):

By TPS you mean Ligthweight Transaction Per Second or just Operation per second .

If it is Operation Per Second .

Figure out whats your Network bandwidth 
Speed of your Disk 
Number of cores on your machine

run queries and at run time figure out what is the bottleneck , commmands to figure out bottleneck are 
* network: dstat 2

- cpu + disk: iostat -c -xc 3
- cpu cores: mpstat -P ALL 1
- memeory : free -m
- gc : jstat -gc pid 2
- do remember either of this bottleneck can be their at server or your client side .